# How to get multiple means scores from a variable in R

Tags: r

here is my example data file.

```
    Animal   Scores
1    Dogs     10
2    Dogs     11
3    Dogs     12
4    Dogs     13
5    Dogs     14
6    Dogs     15
7    Dogs     16
8    Dogs     17
9    Dogs     18
10   Dogs     19
11   Cats     20
12   Cats     21
13   Cats     22
14   Cats     23
15   Cats     24
16   Cats     25
17   Cats     26
18   Cats     27
19   Cats     28
20   Cats     29
21  Birds     30
22  Birds     31
23  Birds     32
24  Birds     33
25  Birds     34
26  Birds     35
27  Birds     36
28  Birds     37
29  Birds     38
30  Birds     39
```

I have only just begun to learn R and am a complete beginner in the coding world hence have been doing this the very very long way.

e.g.

```
>####Separate each animal out 
>dogs <- animaldata$Animal == "Dogs"
>cats <- animaldata$Animal == "Cats"
>birds <- animaldata$Animal == "Birds"

>####Get the means for each animal scores
>dogsmean <- mean(animaldata$Scores[dogs])
>catssmean <- mean(animaldata$Scores[cats])
>birdsmean <- mean(animaldata$Scores[birds])
>
>####Group all means and plot
>Finalmeans <- c(I manually type the numbers of all found means here)
>plot(finalmeans, type="o")
```

I would like an efficient way to get the mean scores for the dogs cats and birds and then plot the mean for each animal on a graph.

P.S. This is my first post! :) I am guessing I have broken most forum posting rules in the process. I'm still figuring it out. All feedback is welcome! :)

Comment: In case you want to provide some data we can directly use, use `dput(animaldata)` or `dput(head(animaldata, 30)` to get just the first 30 lines of your data frame. Makes it easier to show examples with your real data.

Comment: Also, try to paste your code without '>' at the beginning - makes it easy for people to copy-paste your code to see what it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post is fine, don't worry. One possibility to obtain the result you described consists in using the `aggregate()` function:

```
> aggregate( . ~ Animal, animaldata, mean)
#  Animal Scores
#1  Birds   34.5
#2   Cats   24.5
#3   Dogs   14.5
```

Comment: It works! Thanks heaps, just wondering what the (. ~ at the beginning does?

Also if I was in a more complicated df how would I let it know what I wanted to mean of?

Comment: It basically means that all columns should be considered. In this case you would obtain the same result with `aggregate(Scores ~ Animal , animaldata, mean)`

Comment: This second possibility states that you want the mean of "Scores" for different types of "Animals". The downside of not using the "wildcard"  with "." is that only those columns that are explicitly mentioned are kept in the output, i.e., if you had an additional column "weight" it would be dropped, whereas in the case with the "." you would obtain a mean of that value, too.

Answer (score 0):

If your data in a data frame you can use:

```
sapply(levels(animaldata[,1]),function(x) mean(animaldata[animaldata[,1]==x,2]))

Birds  Cats  Dogs 
 34.5  24.5  14.5
```

Answer (score 0):

The `aggregate` function might come in handy for your problem:

```
animaldata <- aggregate(animaldata[, 2:2], list(animaldata$Animal), mean)

> animaldata
  Group.1  x
1    Birds 34.5
2    Cats 24.5
3    Dogs 14.5
```

Here is code to a simple plot of this animal data:

```
par(las=1)
plot(animaldata$Group.1, animaldata$x, xlab="Animal", ylab="Mean Score")
title("Mean Animal Scores")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `ddply` from `plyr` package...

```
library(plyr)
ddply(animaldata, .(Animal), summarise, mean(Scores))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to do it `data.table` way. It is currently the fastest package for this kind of things.

```
library(data.table)
animaldata=data.table(animaldata)
means=animaldata[,.(mean=mean(Scores)),by=Animal]
plot(means$mean,type="o")
```